# How can I perform a LIKE query for a jsonb key?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following jsonb structure:

```
{'this': '1', 'this_that': '0', 'this_and_that': '5'}
```

How do I select rows that contain a LIKE operator?

```
SELECT * FROM myjson WHERE j ? 'this_%'
```

Returns 0 rows...was hoping it would match 'this_that' and 'this_and_that'. (Note: the characters following '_' will potentially vary greatly and therefore I am not able to do an exact match).

Comment: what's the exact version of PostgreSQL you're using ? run `select version()`

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1, 64-bit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your example should not work because there are not implicit cast between `jsonb` and `text` types. You can enforce casting:

```
SELECT '{"this": 1, "this_that": 0, "this_and_that": 5}'::jsonb::text 
            like '%"this%';
```

It is not clean solution. Some better is unpacking json, and filtering over unpacked data with lateral join

```
postgres=# SELECT key FROM  myjson, lateral jsonb_each_text(j) 
             WHERE key LIKE 'this\_%';
┌───────────────┐
│      key      │
╞═══════════════╡
│ this_that     │
│ this_and_that │
└───────────────┘
(2 rows)
```