# How do you use the "LIKE" query for jsonb column types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, hstore, jsonb

For hstore columns in PostgreSQL databases, I know I can use a "LIKE" query like so in Ruby on Rails to search for names that include a certain string:

```
  Product.where("hstore_data -> 'author' LIKE '%billy%'")
```

I tried that for a jsonb column type, but got this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: 
>   operator does not exist: jsonb ~~ unknown
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "products".* FROM
>   "products" WHERE (jsonb_data -> 'author' LIKE '%billy%')

Is there a way to use "LIKE" correctly for jsonb column types?

Comment: [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228984/how-can-i-perform-a-like-query-for-a-jsonb-key)

Comment: Just use [the operator, which returns text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), not json[b]: `->>` (Parentheses might required, -- i.e. `(jsonb_col ->> 'key') LIKE 'pattern'` -- that depends on the PostgreSQL version you use).

Comment: Pozs, great solution! Thank you so much! :) I'll accept your answer of course if you want to add it below. This is what I used:

Product.where("(jsonb_data ->> 'author') LIKE '%billy%'")

 Appreciate the great help. Thank you!!

Comment: I know the answer is already accepted but [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mankind/1802dbb64fc24be33d434d593afd6221) might help to have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

Hope you have

```
product.jsonb_data = {
      author: "billynando"
   }
```

Then

```
Product.where("jsonb_data ->> :key LIKE :value",
  key: "author", value: "%billy%"
)
```

More [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)